# How to get context.type =COPY

Tags: copy, netsuite, suitescript, user-event

I have a userEvent beforesubmitr script. I am trying to detect the context.type as COPY. But, I get the context as CREATE. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

COPY is not a valid `context.type` on the `beforeSubmit()` event.  It is only valid during `beforeLoad()`.

Compare the documentation for [beforeLoad(context)](https://suiteanswers.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/44545) and [beforeSubmit(context)](https://suiteanswers.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/44546). You will see COPY is not listed under `beforesubmit`.  This makes sense if you think about it; the copying all happens immediately after you click the Copy button in the UI, before the new (copied) record is displayed.  After that, it's a new record in its own right, so on `beforeSubmit` it will have a `context.type` of CREATE.